# Creating a default backend for helm nginx-ingress result in CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to set a default backend for my ingress-nginx installed with helm chart on an AKS cluster. When using the "regular" default backend (defaultbackend-amd64) everything works as expected.

### Deafult backend image

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:alpine
USER root
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

#### nginx.conf

```
user                            root;
worker_processes                auto;

error_log                       /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

events {
    worker_connections          1024;
}

http {
    include                     /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type                application/octet-stream;
    sendfile                    off;
    access_log                  off;
    keepalive_timeout           3000;
    server {
        listen                  0.0.0.0:8080;
        root                    /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index                   index.html;
        server_name             localhost;
        client_max_body_size    16m;
    }
}
```

#### index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>404</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Custom 404
    </body>
</html>
```

#### nginx-ingress configuration

```
ACR_URL=<my-act-registry>
SOURCE_REGISTRY=k8s.gcr.io
CONTROLLER_IMAGE=ingress-nginx/controller
CONTROLLER_TAG=v1.2.1
PATCH_IMAGE=ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen
PATCH_TAG=v1.1.1
DEFAULTBACKEND_IMAGE=<default-backend-image>
DEFAULTBACKEND_TAG=<default-backend-tag>
DEFAULTBACKEND_SHA256=<default-backend-sha>

helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --version 4.1.3 \
    --namespace ingress-basic \
    --create-namespace \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.image.registry=$ACR_URL \
    --set controller.image.image=$CONTROLLER_IMAGE \
    --set controller.image.tag=$CONTROLLER_TAG \
    --set controller.image.digest="" \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.registry=$ACR_URL \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.image=$PATCH_IMAGE \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.tag=$PATCH_TAG \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.digest="" \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.image.registry=$ACR_URL \
    --set defaultBackend.image.image=$DEFAULTBACKEND_IMAGE \
    --set defaultBackend.image.tag=$DEFAULTBACKEND_TAG \
    --set defaultBackend.image.digest="" \
    --debug
```

### Error metrics

#### default backend logs

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: can not modify /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (read-only file system?)
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2022/11/01 10:31:31 [warn] 1#1: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
2022/11/01 10:31:31 [emerg] 1#1: mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (30: Read-only file system)
nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (30: Read-only file system)
```

#### Extra information

The image runs just fine in local docker environment, it also works if deployed in the cluster as an indipendent deploy. I'm thinking this is some kind of security issue with nginx-ingress. Any help with this? Or maybe is it possible to set the indipendent service as default backend for nginx-ingress helm chart ? (eg. --set defaultbackend.service/port)

#### Fix

[How to customize error pages served via the default backend of an nginx ingress controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60233958/how-to-customize-error-pages-served-via-the-default-backend-of-an-nginx-ingress)

David answer for this question solved the problem but i'm not sure why it did, so the answer will remain open